# SQL remove results from list

Tags: sql

I have a Locations table, and a Visit table. Each location need to be visited annually based on a particular visit type. When we log a Visit, we add the type of visit it is and for what location (date time and all that other stuff). I need to deduce from what we collect, those locations that have not been visited.

For example, Locations A-Z (26 locations) can have 3 types of visits (Meeting, Review and Annual).

Some locations might not get visited at all while others might get visited more than once.

I need to know which locations have not had an Annual visit.

The SQL Statement that i have seems to give me a list of locations that have had an annual visit but i dont see a way of either eliminating that one entry from the larger list OR possible filtering the large list .

```sql
SELECT
     Location.Name
    ,Location.ID
    ,Visit.Date
    ,Visit.Time
    ,Visit.Visit_Type
FROM Location
INNER JOIN Visit
    ON Location.ID = Visit.LocationID
WHERE Visit.Group_Type = 'School'
AND ( Visit.Date BETWEEN '2021' AND '2022' )
```

Comment: If you are looking for Locations with missing Visits then the INNER JOIN and WHERE clause above will do you no good.

Comment: A left join where the left joined data returns all nulls (no data) or using the EXISTS would be two ways to find those records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to check for the lack of an annual, visit using the EXISTS statement.

```
SELECT        
   L.Name, L.ID
FROM          
   Location L             
WHERE 
   NOT EXISTS
   (
       SELECT 
          * 
       FROM 
          Visit V2 
       WHERE 
          V2.LocationID = L.LocationID 
          AND V2.Group_Type = 'School' 
          AND ( V2.Date BETWEEN '2021' AND '2022' )
   )
```

Comment: Thank you! the NOT EXISTS worked beautifully. I modified a little. i added the group type above the NOT EXISTS and put in a Visit_Type = 'Annual'. after verifying a few lines of data, this seems to work!

Answer (score 0):

**Schema (MySQL v8.0)**

```
CREATE TABLE location (
  `name` VARCHAR(8),
  `id` INTEGER
);

INSERT INTO location
  (`name`, `id`)
VALUES
  ('here', '1'),
  ('there', '2'),
  ('anywhere', '3');

CREATE TABLE visit (
  `id` INTEGER,
  `type` VARCHAR(7)
);

INSERT INTO visit
  (`id`, `type`)
VALUES
  ('1', 'meeting'),
  ('1', 'review'),
  ('2', 'meeting'),
  ('2', 'annual'),
  ('3', 'annual');
```

---

**No Annual Visit**

```
SELECT name
FROM location
JOIN visit 
USING(id)
GROUP BY name
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN type = 'annual' THEN 1 END) = 0;
```

| name |
| --- |
| here |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hBeUuVA8Sd6FmifCccb7GT/0)

Comment: What if there existed a Location such as - > ('novisits', '4');

Comment: I think I see your point, though it's poorly explained in the form of a useless question. A left join would be safer here.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a list of all visits this year, then use an OUTER JOIN to find the locations that haven't been visited this year yet.

```
   ;WITH visitsThisYear AS
    (
        SELECT
        *
        FROM
          Visit
        WHERE 
            Visit.Group_Type = 'School'
            AND ( Visit.Date BETWEEN '2021' AND '2022' )
    ),        
    SELECT 
      Location.Name,
      Location.ID
    FROM
      LOCATION
        LEFT OUTER JOIN visitsThisYear
           ON Location.ID = visitsThisYear.LocationID
    WHERE Location.ID IS NULL
```